# What is the origin of the "time" field in the Velodyne ROS 2 driver?

Tags: ros2, velodyne

When point field data is published by the ROS 2 Velodyne LIDAR, it includes a "time" field. I am trying to find out how this field is calculated. Is it:

`time = absolute_firing_time - header_stamp.timestamp[0]` ?

Also If anyone can share a ros2 bag of velodyne lidar data for my analysis, that would be great too, so I can play it.

Comment: Unfortunately people here likely won't be able to share their datasets with you, since Stack Exchange is not a forum:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums

Answer (score 1):

These are the lines that handle publishing the Velodyne point cloud data, from the [ROS Velodyne driver](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/blob/29abd0e1361cb7f5eda451d2b51c35eeca45e0d5/velodyne_driver/src/driver/driver.cc#L268-L277):

```
  // publish message using time of last packet read
  ROS_DEBUG("Publishing a full Velodyne scan.");
  if (config_.timestamp_first_packet){
    scan->header.stamp = scan->packets.front().stamp;
  }
  else{
    scan->header.stamp = scan->packets.back().stamp;
  }
  scan->header.frame_id = config_.frame_id;
  output_.publish(scan);
```

As described there, it's informed by the packet as sent from the Velodyne. I would expect this to be when the distances are *read* by the sensor not when the emissions are sent: you aren't expected to be doing the time-of-flight math yourself, you just want to know where things are in your environment.

For Non-velodyne LIDARs, I would expect similar behavior. A very common pattern is to read sensor data into a message, then provide a timestamp, then publish.